# send data through post from android to node.js?

Tags: java, android, node.js, http-post

I use nodejs as server and java(android) as client,i succes send data through post from android to node. but my problem when android send the data (string) consist of **space** and **new line (enter)** its received on node but the character was change,

for example,i send this string from android

```
Hello
I learn android
```

the string send to node and received,but i get this in node

```
Hello%0AI+learn+android
```

I use this code for send string to node in android.

```
 public void btnOnClick(){
      String text= URLEncoder.encode(editText.getText().toString(), "utf-8"); //I get from editText and convert to utf-8
      sendToNode(text);

}


public void sendToNode(String text){
    try {                       

                 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://myDomain.com:8888/");
                 UrlEncodedFormEntity form;
                 try {
                     Log.i("kirim ke node isitextAsli ",text);
                     List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


                     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("datanah",text));
                     form=new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8");
                     httppost.setEntity(form);

                     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


                     Log.i("HTTP Post", "Response from server node = " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase() + "  Code = " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                 } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                     Log.e("HTTP Post", "Protocol error = " + e.toString());
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     Log.e("HTTP Post", "IO error = " + e.toString());
       }
}
```

and I use this code for receive string in node

```
req.addListener('data', function(chunk) { data += chunk; });
req.addListener('end', function() {
    console.log("from android :"+data); //result of data is Hello%0AI+learn+android 

});
```

How i solve my problem?

please help,Thanks.

Comment: Do you check the value in the "text"? what is the value in it?

Comment: yes i do,the value is Hello%0AI+learn+android because i encode the text to utf

Comment: you need res.on("data"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string is URL-encoded, as you explicitly asked for in your code (and need for a regular POST). Decode it on the server.

To decode it on the server side, do:

```
var querystring = require('querystring'); 
querystring.unescape(data.replace(/\+/g, " "));
```

Comment: how to decode in server?i've tried use manual code using text.replace(/+/," ") it doesn't work.

Comment: Node.js has a builtin function to do that. 
Try 
`var querystring = require('querystring');`
`querystring.unescape(data);`

Comment: @FMontano: i try and work in some case,only new line(enter) work,but space still to be "+" not " "

Comment: @ltvie, try `querystring.unescape(data.replace(/\+/g, " "));`

Answer (score 0):

The following is the sample of encoding and decoding, YOU WANT TO DECODE IN THE SERVER PART

```
        String encoded;  
        try {  
            encoded = URLEncoder.encode(input, "UTF-8");  

        System.out.println("URL-encoded by client with UTF-8: " + encoded);  

        String incorrectDecoded = URLDecoder.decode(encoded, "ISO-8859-1");  
        System.out.println("Then URL-decoded by server with ISO-8859-1: " + incorrectDecoded);  

        String correctDecoded = URLDecoder.decode(encoded, "UTF-8");  
        System.out.println("Server should URL-decode with UTF-8: " + correctDecoded);  
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
```